# using polymer with typescript

Tags: typescript, polymer

i have created files:

**card.html:**

```
<polymer-element name="card" constructor="Card">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="card.css">
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script src="card.js"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**card.js:**

```
class Card {

    ready() {
    }

    leftView() {
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use polymer with typescript, as i understand class Card should extend Polymer class which extends Node just don't understand how to do .

Answer (score 2):

Your TypeScript (should be `card.ts`, not `card.js`) could look like this:

```
class Card extends HTMLElement {
    ready() {
        alert("made a card");
    }
}

Polymer('x-card', Card.prototype);
```

**Note**: if you put code in a `constructor` method, it will never run (because of arcana in the way custom elements are marshaled at the browser level).

You will have to compile your typescript into javascript to try it. Also, remember that custom element names must contain a dash, so:

```
<polymer-element name="x-card" constructor="Card">
```

Comment: HTMLElement is an Interface in lib.d.ts, a class cannot extend an interface. How did you manage to have this working? Are you using version 1.0 of typescript or a previous one?

Comment: I do not use TypeScript in general. I remember testing only in the TypeScript playground back when I answered this question.

Comment: The Card class must chain to the HTMLElement prototype. This is the point of my answer. How you achieve this in TypeScript is a matter for TypeScript. This does still work in the Playground, fwiw.

Comment: After your last comment you still think this a valid answer? You're passing the prototype. In the remote possibility it worked, could you include in your answer the generated javascript? And also include a property. Then you'll see what I meant.

Comment: didn't you see the error in the Playground: "A class may only extend another class."

Comment: You are right, sorry for the confusion. As I said, I don't use TypeScript, and all I've been trying to communicate is that the class must chain to HTMLElement.protoytpe. In JS, this would be Card = function(){}; Card.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype). You know TypeScript, so can you provide the correct TS syntax for this?